# Rasterize a geometry using gdal.RasterizeLayer()

Tags: gdal, qgis-3, rasterization

I am writing a processing script using QGIS 3.4. I need to rasterize a polygon using `gdal.RasterizeLayer`. The problem is the polygon is a list of `QgsGeometry` objects and not a layer.

```
n = (2*radiusInt)+1
epsg = bldgs_lyr.sourceCrs().authid()[5:]
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(int(epsg))
geotransform = (sourceX-radius, 1, 0, sourceY+radius, 0, -1)

output_rast = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(raster_uri, n, n, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
output_rast.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
output_rast.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs="+bldgs_lyr.sourceCrs().authid(), 'polygon', 'memory')
prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()
for geom in geometries:
    feat = QgsFeature()
    feat.setGeometry(geom)
    prov.addFeatures([feat])

gdal.RasterizeLayer(output_rast, [1], mem_layer, burn_values=1)
```

As you can see, I've tried creating a vector layer to use as input. But if I run this, QGIS will just crash.